# Anaconda navigator VERY slow

Tags: anaconda, conda

My anaconda navigator takes 2-3 minutes to start. I have proxy setting set correctly and I can use conda install with no problem.

Why is Anaconda Navigator so slow?

Comment: Same problem; and not only is it slow for loading, it's slow for everything: even mouse and keyboard events lag so much that abandoned using Navigator altogether; it's just too slow.

Answer (score 40):

I had the same problem. My issue was the ssl verification as I assume my workplace has done something with Firewall or etc. So I took the following two steps to fix it:
- open command prompt (`cmd.exe`)
- You can see the list of conda settings: `conda config --show`
- Disable the ssl verification: `conda config --set ssl_verify False`

Now launch the Anaconda. If it takes time, wait! It will finally load.
- Go to File->Preferences (shortkey: Ctrl+P)
- Make sure to uncheck the "Enable SSL verification". (attached image)
- Don't forget to click on the Apply button.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc09h.png)

That made the trick and Anaconda loads very fast!

Comment: It's not just the best answer, it's **the only answer** to the problem!

Comment: this worked for me on my Mac mini M1, did not follow the command, simply selected cntrl+p and then unchecked the SSL bit, now it loads in less than a second!

Answer (score 10):

I stumbled upon this problem in two pc which had I5 / I7 processor(Win 10 / Win 8) with SSD.
This is how I fixed up the problem, now it takes around **20 second** to boot Anaconda Navigator and all the apps) :

Open your prompt / CMD and type :

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

Also looks into your Antivirus : 
*they may isolate or block Anaconda because they could see it as a threat*

Do a tour into your Antivirus/HIP/Firewall/Trusted applications and grant Anaconda full permission

Comment: Updating both conda and anaconda is basically a contradiction, see [What is the right way to update Anaconda and Conda base & environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701571/what-is-the-right-way-to-update-anaconda-and-conda-base-environments)

Comment: Will it Launch any faster ?

Comment: This leads to another related problem. Updates take several hours to finish.

Comment: @Peter In defense of Fedeco, that is the official way to update anaconda according to its documentation https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/

Comment: After 1 year, I can only say that what I posted was what worked for me, even through it's a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

I have one shortcut here, 
Go to search bar and type jupyter or if you want spyder
Type spyder , so you can directly open it. No need to start anaconda

Here I saw

https://youtu.be/xNOg5VfCDWU

Comment: Better if you cab add more detail in SO, what could be if your link not work in future?

Answer (score 2):

I started Anaconda Navigator with "Run as Administrator" privileges on my Windows machine, and it worked like a charm. Though it did ask me for Admin credentials for a couple of times while loading different scripts, but the response was <1 min, compared to 6 - 8 mins. earlier.

1. Search for Anaconda through desktop search or go to Cortana tool on the desktop toolbar and type Anaconda
2. On the Anaconda icon that shows up, right-click and choose "Run as Administrator"
3. Provide Admin credentials when prompted

This should hopefully work for Windows 10 users.

Answer (score 1):

I as well had problem of Anaconda Navigator starting after long time ( 5-10 mins) on my Windows 10 machine. After defining proxy settings in .condarc file and OS ENV variable, it reduced to 1-1.5 min. See if it works for you :).

**Changes in .condarc file**

```
proxy_servers: 
        http: http://yourhttpproxy:port
        https: https://yourhttpsproxy:port
```

---

**Updating OS ENV variable like:**

```
HTTP_PROXY= http://yourhttpproxy:port 
HTTPS_PROXY = https://yourhttpsproxy:port
```

---

Answer (score 1):

*This worked like magic especially if you are using a machine with vpn enabled & proxy
If you know the specific app you are running e.g R, Jupyter e.t.c just simply:

1. Go to the Windows search button
2. Type the name e.g Jupyter

   3. Click on it and it opens the notepad!

Answer (score 0):

After encountering the same issue (stucking at loading apps for 6 min), I tried the previous which didn't work. Furthermore, I have also tried to reinstall anaconda without any success.

After a while I tried to tape:"jupyter lab" (or jupyter notebook) on ANACONDA PROMPT. It works for me, now I do not need to start anaconda navigator and then going to jupyter lab or notebook.

Hope it will be helpful for some of you.