# The Anaconda launcher takes long time to load

Tags: python, arrays, anaconda, conda

I'm new to coding and decided to install Anaconda because I heard it was the most practical platform for beginners.

The problem is, every time I try opening it, it literally takes at least 15 minutes to boot up while showing me `"Updating metadata..."` and subsequently showing me `"Updating repodata..."` statements.

Would any of you know how to fix or go around this issue?

I'm using a macbook air that has 8gb of RAM and an i5 processor, if that helps.

Comment: Never had this issue... try re-installing anaconda from scratch?

Comment: did you try to remove and re-install doing what is describe here : https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install ?

Comment: This might be an internet connection speed issue too

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933243/anaconda-navigator-very-slow/43892956#43892956

Answer (score 0):

Some time restart works. I was also facing same issue, when I restarted my system it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I started Anaconda Navigator with "Run as Administrator" privileges on my Windows machine, and it worked like a charm. Though it did ask me for Admin credentials for a couple of times while loading different scripts, but the response was <1 min, compared to 6 - 8 mins. earlier.

Search for Anaconda through desktop search or go to Cortana tool on the desktop toolbar and type Anaconda
On the Anaconda icon that shows up, right-click and choose "Run as Administrator"
Provide Admin credentials when prompted
This should hopefully work for Windows 10 users.