# Python command prompt very slow to appear (Anaconda)

Tags: python, anaconda, command-prompt

I've lately noticed an increasing lag when I fire up the CMD window to run python.
Immediately after entering "python", I see the python version info, but instead of the command prompt (>>>) I just get a blinking cursor (not showing in screenshot). After what's now become a couple of minutes, the command prompt finally appears, and I can run python code as usual.
[image: CMD screenshot - Python missing command prompt]

When this happens, the CPU on my little work laptop is clearly under heavy load, the fan goes way up.
I have basically the same setup on my home PC (still with the older Anaconda and python 3.7) and never had any problems like this.

I was running python 3.7 in Anaconda on Windows 10. I just do simple scripts, copy and paste the code in a terminal window. In my original version, I had the base env + one clone, both had this problem.

I tried updating conda and anaconda but nothing changed. I thought it might be some dependency conflicts (I had recently pip-installed a couple of heavy-ish packages into my clone env: pytessearct and openpyxl), so I finally uninstalled Anaconda and reinstalled the latest version (Anaconda3-2020.07-Windows-x86_64 with python 3.8) with the standard packages, and I still have the same problem.

One related clue: Anaconda Navigator was also hecka slow to load. I tried disabling SSL verification per this thread ([Anaconda navigator VERY slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933243/anaconda-navigator-very-slow)) but it had no effect on the time delay for the python command prompt. But with the fresh install, Navigator now loads normally.

In my new install, I did the same setup, base + clone, both with the standard Anaconda package set, no add-ons, I still have the same problem in both envs.

Comment: New clue: when I type exit() at the end of a python run, the same thing happens - blinking cursor, CPU fan whines, takes forever to get back to the conda shell prompt.

Comment: I never really figured out the problem, but it may have been just Windows running out of swap file - I noticed the hard disk was getting full and other programs were slow, so I did a massive cleanup. I also removed Anaconda using the anaconda-clean utility, then installed Miniconda, then added Navigator and just the packages I needed. The Miniconda3 folder is now under 2 GB, compared to ~10 GB for the full Anaconda base + full clone. All is good now. Lesson learned, keep your Windows clean!

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but I wanted to add a suggestion not seen here that I experienced.  I have anaconda installed on a non-system drive (on my d:\ in windows 10) and recently noticed a unusually slow startup (maybe 1-2 minutes?) before the anaconda prompt loaded.  When the prompt finally released the system to me, I got into jupyter notebooks realized I'd closed several jupyter notebooks incorrectly and they were still being seen active/open.  When I force halted those notebooks from within jupyter notebooks the anaconda prompt boot speeds subsequently dropped back to range of 10-15 seconds.  I don't know if it's the problem, but is the one thing I changed and noticed a difference.